# How to using same TCP connection for http2.0 and async in okhttp3?

Tags: okhttp

Move from https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/6051

This is a problem with okhttp keepalived connections, I wonder how to deal with this issue.

```
OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .sslSocketFactory(factory, (X509TrustManager) TRUST_MANAGERS[0])
                .hostnameVerifier((s, sslSession) -> true)
                .protocols(Arrays.asList(Protocol.HTTP_2, Protocol.HTTP_1_1))
                .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
                .connectionPool(new ConnectionPool(5, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                .build();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://example.com/")
                .build();

int count = 2;

long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

final CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(count);

for (int i = 1; i <= count; ++i) {
    httpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "-failed-" + e.getMessage());
                    finish();
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                    finish();
                }

                private void finish() {
                    countDownLatch.countDown();
                }

            });

    }

        countDownLatch.await();

        System.out.println("Time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) );

        System.exit(0);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use LoggingEventListener if you want to see what is going on.

Generally when we first connect we can't know ahead of time that a single connection will be http/2 and able to serve both requests. So when the connection pool is empty, OkHttp will establish 2 connections, discover they are both http/2 and then disconnect one.

So likely both requests use a single connection, but you see two established.

You have a few options

1) Don't worry, let it create two connections temporarily, and OkHttp will close one as soon as it realises it has two HTTP/2 connections.

2) Use a warmup request to create the first request, then only create secondary requests to the same host once you have received a connectionAcquired event on that first request.

But I'd encourage you not to worry and just let OkHttp do it's thing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I used #2).Use a warmup request to create the first request. However, Warmup doesn't follow my code logic.

Comment: Could't we actively configure using HTTP2.0 to avoid creating redundant TCP connection?  Look forward to your reply.

Comment: And if use the first options, when I send 100 simultaneous requests, the okhttp will creating 100 TLS/CP connections. 

Even though okhttp turns off 99 connections, but it causes waste of resources.

Comment: Finally a thread relevant to what I observed in Wireshark. Is there an option to avoid this behavior? Unnecessary SSL handshakes on server end.

Comment: You could make a feature request to OkHttp, to assume HTTP/2 or remember it. But otherwise the warmup request is the best option.